# SQL pyodbc issue

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I try to execute the following query as a prepared statement:

```
self.cursor.execute("select distinct ? from isap.tn_documentation where ? = '?' and  ? <> ''", attribute2, attribute1, i.text(0), attribute2)
```

After execution i get the following error:

> The SQL contains 3 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied', 'HY000

Comment: You shouldn't have to single-quote the text literal in the predicate. That may be the issue.

Comment: Without the quotes, i will get a wrong result.

Comment: I don't think that's true. The prepare call goes to server and should obtain type information, the use of which should allow the client to bind the parameters correctly. (If I remember correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass column names as query parameters. You would need to concatenate the column names in the query string (while keeping the column values as parameters).

This should look like:

```
self.cursor.execute(
    "select distinct " 
        + attribute2 
        + " from isap.tn_documentation where " 
        + attribute1 + " = ? and " + attribute2 + " <> ''", 
    i.text(0)
)
```

Please note that doing so exposes your code to SQL injection: if your attributes input are coming from outside your code, this is a severe security breach. You would need to ensure that they do not contain malicious data (for example by checking the value of each attribute against a fixed list of allowed values: this should be quite easy since we are dealing with column names).